# MySQL: Why is that when creating a schema with collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci it becomes utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Tags: mysql, collation

When I create a schema with collition utf8mb4_unicode_ci it becomes collition utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (using Workbench). Even when the default settings of the server have collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci set it still becomes utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

`` CREATE SCHEMA `new_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; ``

This gives issues with foreign key constrains with another database while importing the database. The only way to fix it is to set the columns for the constrains manually one by one to collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Once I do that the constrains can be made.

Hope someone can explain why this happens and has an answer how to prevent it.

Best,
Ted

@Rick James, This is the output you requested:

[image]

Comment: Looks to me there is still a setting overriding the collation to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. Also this seems to happen only on MySQL 8 or higher, can you confirm this?

Comment: What version are you using?  And please show us the output from `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VALUE LIKE 'utf%';`.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev It is happening with version 5.7.

Comment: @RickJames See the original post for the result of the query.

Comment: Weird that this happens on version 5.7, seeing as `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` only got introduced at [version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html). Is there something in the import setting the collation perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The Workbench table inspector is not showing the collation that was set.

Run `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your_schema;` and you'll see the collation that was set. Or even in Workbench's Shema Inspector the correct collation is displayed.